# Ant: property name containing a timestamp

Tags: ant, properties, timestamp, macrodef

Regarding the timestamp variable in the ant script, I can see how to build it using a `macrodef`, but I don't see the way to read it afterwards, even though its name was saved in a variable.

```
<macrodef name="macro1">
  <attribute name="propName"/>
  <attribute name="propValue"/>
  <sequential>
    <property name="@{propName}" value="@{propValue}"/>
    <echo>   dans macrodef $${@{propName}} : ${@{propName}}</echo>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<tstamp>                                                              
     <format property="rightNow" pattern="yyyyMMdd"  locale="en,UK" />
</tstamp>                        
<var name="nomProp" value="${rightNow}"/>
<macro1 propName="${rightNow}" propValue="at Paris"/>
```

When the property is named, it is ok, but this is useless :

```
<echo>property $${20170531} content : ${20170531}</echo>
```

...so what is the trick to get it ? this syntax does not work

```
<echo> property $${nomProp} content : ${${nomProp}}</echo>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have found the way to do it using the nested properties : First download the ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar.zip file, install the jar file in the ant/lib structure, secondly, declare props in the Ant scrip project header ( <project name="mine" xmlns:props="antlib:org.apache.ant.props"> ) and add the following code :<propertyhelper>
       <props:nested />
     </propertyhelper>

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Why do you want the property's name to be set dynamically? I get the impression what you're trying to do can be accomplished with vanilla Ant, but I can't say for sure without knowing your goals/requirements.

Comment: My goal was to use a resultproperty in an "exec" ant task located in a loop (for), so I needed a unique property name for each instance of my loop. Defining a property having a timestamp in its name provides the trick, reason why I needed this nested facility.